# Tab not working properly in Python

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I have been using NotePAD++ for editing Python scripts.
I recently downloaded the PyDEV IDE (for Eclipse).
The problem is that when I wrote the scripts in NotePad++ I used "TAB" for indentation, and now when I open them with PyDEV, every time I try to write a new line instead of "TABS" PyDEV inserts spaces. (even if I click the "TAB" key Eclipse inserts 4 spaces instead of one tab).
This raises indentation error.

Is there anyway to fix this thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, follow http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ which states:

> Indentation
>
> ```
> Use 4 spaces per indentation level.
> ```

Replace all your tabs with spaces, and set Notepad++ to use spaces instead of tabs.

Setting Eclipse to use tabs instead of spaces would be a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that :/
Do you know if there is anyway to convert them fast (or do I need to go line by line)?

Comment: @Joel search and replace: \t by 4 spaces

Comment: Thanks, didnt know it can find \t but with reg-exp it does :)

Comment: There is an extensive discussion about tabs vs spaces here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119562/tabs-versus-spaces-in-python-programming , which I would summarize as "there really isn't a better or worse way (but there are a lot of fanatics)". So I would say, if you already have and like tabs, save yourself the effort and keep them.

Answer (score 4):

Tabs are problematic—different people can choose different widths in their editor settings, and then you have bad formatting (for e.g. C) or execution problems (Python). So spaces are better for getting consistently sensible results. But one issue with that is that some editors still default to using tabs.

In the companies I've worked for, our coding guidelines have specified that we should always use spaces, no tabs. But default editor settings sometimes catch us out.

In Eclipse with PyDev, the fast way to convert tabs to spaces is the menu item Source⇒Convert tabs to space-tabs.

Comment: *different people can choose different widths in their editor settings, and then you have bad formatting* Really? How come setting number of spaces displayed per tab can cause bad formatting?

Comment: @Piotr: Two main reasons: (1) Using tabs to align trailing comments—the comments trailing lines of different lengths will be mis-aligned depending on the tab width. (2) Mixed with editors/tools configured for spaces, but different tab widths, you'll end up with lines mis-aligned for various tab settings. I admit (2) only affects a mix of spaces and tabs (as in the original question), so that shouldn't be an issue if you can guarantee pure tabs-only.

Comment: @Craig: I agree that using tabs to align trailing comments is a bad idea. However, using tabs for indentation (that is, strictly at line beginnings only) is a completely different story, and in my opinion tabs make a lot more sense for that than spaces. I find it rather annoying how some editor religiously insist on using spaces everywhere.

Comment: @Craig regarding your first point:

(1) _Using tabs to align trailing comments—the comments trailing lines of different lengths will be mis-aligned depending on the tab width._

This reasoning is only correct, if you ignore elastic tab stops. If your editor supports elastic tab stops, than tabs are actually superior to spaces for this case as well. See http://nickgravgaard.com/elastictabstops/

Answer (score 3):

Putting aside the tabs vs spaces argument.

To fix this you need to
chose 'toggle force tabs' in preferences for eclipse to use tabs instead of the default spaces.